# Почему обновлять ссылки это плохо?

Tags: python, переменные, ссылки

Почему плохо делать замену ссылок у переменных?

Например, изначально у нас был массив:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
```

Мы обновили ссылку у переменой `mylist`, используя `list comprehension`, и теперь `mylist` ссылается на новый массив:

```
mylist = [x for x in mylist if x % 2 == 0]
```

Что в этом плохого?

Какой в этом криминал против читаемости кода?

Неужели, когда мы проходимся по строкам в файле, каждую строку, к которой мы применили `strip()` нужно ссылать на отдельную переменную? То есть:

```
for line in lines:
    temp_line = line.strip()
    print(temp_line)
```

Вместо такой:

```
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    print(line)
```

А если инструкций много?

Comment: @jfs, вопрос специально для тебя

Comment: Вы необратимо потеряли оригинальное значение переменной `mylist`-единственное, что на ум приходит.Потеря значения и контекста ведет ко многим последствиям.Например,другой программист(не вы)или вы через 2 года будете быстро просматривать код,пропустите глазами сточку с переопределением и из-за этого у вас сложится неверное представление о работе метода,что теоретически может привести к ошибкам.Это все из области "теоретически приведет к ошибкам в будущем",чем к каким-то жестким правилам и законам.Но эти правила появились неспроста и когда вы будете просматривать чужой код,то еще вспомните о них

Comment: @m9_psy хранение всех промежуточных переменных приведёт к путанице намного быстрее, так как читающий программист может подумать, что они ещё на самом деле зачем-то нужны. Нечего строчки пропускать)

Comment: @m9_psy вот-вот, `andreymal` дело говорит. Нагромождать код большим количеством переменных - плохая идея. Зачем мне оригинал списка, если мне нужны только чётные значения из него и работать я буду только с ними?

Comment: С другой стороны, можно делать `новое = [чтототам for x in старое]; del старое`, но лично мне это тоже не очень нравится

Comment: @KitScribe, а откуда это утверждение - `плохо делать замену ссылок у переменных` - вы можете дать ссылку?

Comment: @MaxU да, конечно. [Прошу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/654980/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%8F/654988#comment939590_654988)

Comment: @KitScribe, ну так назовите свою переменную как "Только четные" = [...], а старую оставьте в покое, как "user_input" или еще чего. Хорошо заданный вопрос = половина ответа, так и тут: хорошо названная переменная = половина метода. Новая переменная с явным именем облегчила бы понимание кода, программисту бы не пришлось даже понимать, что там в цикле происходит - он видит название и только из него понимает, что это массив из четных.

Comment: @m9_psy ну **тут же идёт абстрактный пример**. А в реальной жизни **на практике оригинальная переменная может ссылаться и не на массив изначально и называться уже логически верно**. После преобразования мы можем получить нужные нам данные, имя ссылки которых идеально совпадает с именем ссылки данных, которые мы преобразовывали

Comment: @KitScribe думаю, jfs говорил как раз про практику

Comment: @KitScribe, какие еще абстрактные примеры? Программирование - это инженерно-техническая дисциплина, тут все предельно конкретно и по делу (один из принципов SE - на конкретный вопрос - конкретный ответ) - вы не можете вот так просто съехать с вопроса фразой "это все абстракции" до тех пор, пока не опишите эти абстракции полностью и исчерпывающе. На все есть ограничения, серебряных пуль и универсальных ответов нет. Опишите тогда "пример из жизни" - из своего или чужого кода, который подтверждал бы ваш тезис о том, что можно переопределять переменные так, как вам вздумается

Comment: @m9_psy вы не совсем меня поняли, как я понимаю. Вы сейчас **пытаетесь мне навязать практику сумбурного переопределения и анархии**, **когда я** в свою очередь **говорю о грамотном переопределении**, как в случае с `line = line.strip()` или `data = groupby(data)`

Comment: @KitScribe, как вы определили "грамотность" своих примеров? Есть какие-то метрики, чтобы численно измерить грамотность кода? Если вы такую метрику изобрели, то можете озолотиться на анализаторе. Я серьезно. То, что вы выбрали примеры, в которых не имеет особого смысла сохранять значение переменной не означает, что нет контр примеров, где такое значение необходимо и в самом простом случае "хранить или нет" зависит от конкретной задачи. Сложите с принципом, что название переменной должно отражать ее суть (тут-то вопросов нет?) и будет вам ответ "хранить или нет".

Comment: @m9_psy **Уважаемый m9_psy, само собой, если оригинал переменной будет необходим, то ссылку обновлять не следует**, это ясно даже самому тупому программисту, как мне кажется (возможно, самому тупому и не ясно, конечно), поэтому данный фактор не поднимался. Речь идёт про те случаи, когда **преобразование происходит для того, чтобы работать с преобразованными данными, когда исходные данные нам не нужны**. Я, честно, не пойму, вы хотите докопаться до того, что вопрос не содержит в себе чёткого описания всех возможных вариантов развития событий? Или вы погрязли в жажде одержать победу в полемике?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things. -- Phil Karlton

Не стоит путать [`line = line.strip()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/466691/23044) и [`array = groupby(array)`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/654988/1) случаи. Первое нормально как правило, а второе стоит избегать. Строка без окружающего пробела (в задаче, где этот пробел не является важным) остаётся строкой (c точки зрения задачи это те же данные, та же роль, та же ответственность), а `groupby(array)` объект слабо на массив похож (к примеру, `list(array)` создаст копию, оставив array как есть, но вызов `list` на groupby-объекте его исчерпает, что к багу может вести).

Для контекста: [@Kit Scribe написал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/654988/1):

```
from itertools import groupby

array = [4, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 1, 6, 9, 9, 2]

array = groupby(array) # получаем элемент groupby

new_array = []

for elem, grouper in array:
    new_array.append(list(grouper)) # если не проводить преобразование получим itertools._grouper object
                                    # да и к тому же, нам всё равно нужен list, так что...

print(new_array) # [[4], [2, 2], [4], [5, 5, 5], [1], [6], [9, 9], [2]]
```

в ответ на вопрос как можно одинаковые идущие подряд элементы сгруппировать во вложенные списки: из `array = [4, 2, 2, 4]` получить `[[4], [2, 2], [4]]` (само использование `groupby()` здесь совершенно оправдано, эта функция очень хорошо подходит для этой задачи).

На что [я оставил комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/654980/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%8f/654988#comment939264_654988):

> Старайтесь не использовать одно и то же имя в одном и том же контексте для разных вещей (избегайте `array = groupby(array)`). Вместо этого к примеру:
>   `nested = [list(same_items) for _, same_items in groupby(array)]`

Почему [`array = groupby(array)` стоит избегать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/654980/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%8f/654988#comment939264_654988)? Потому что это может создать путаницу, которую легко можно избежать (просто в for-цикл передайте как я показал).

В трёх строчках, даже если вы все лучшие практики нарушите, как правило, можно раскопать что код делает, но в реальном коде больше трёх строчек и нет возможности вникать в каждую во всей кодовой базе. Подумайте о будущих читателей кода (вы сами, через полгода, когда вы уже забыли что и как код делает, а вам надо его расширить/исправить, при этом всё это надо было сделать ещё вчера), если возможную путаницу легко устранить (как в этом случае), то это следует сделать. В тему: [Should I reuse variables?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/115520/1985)

Comment: Ответ не очень раскрывает суть вопроса. Иными словами, он абстрактен. **Если нам нужно получить массив массивов идущих подряд элементов и при этом нам не нужен исходный массив**, то почему нам просто не заменить ссылку? `CPython` автоматически уничтожит массив после этого, например, не дожидаясь работы сборщика мусора, как заметил **andreymal**, что в свою очередь плюс

Comment: @KitScribe, эффективность кода тут ни при чем.  Речь о том, что семантически аргумент и результат функции `groupby` - это очень разные обертки для одних и тех же в сущности данных. Их скорее всего нельзя обработать одинаково, передать один как заменитель другого в какой-то метод или цикл ( в отличие от того же `line = line.strip()`).

Answer (score 4):

До первого запуска сборщика мусора все будет плохо ;) Если не оставлять в памяти гигабайтные массивы, то париться нет смысла – те, кто беспокоятся о быстроте кода и эффективности используемой им памяти на с/с++ пишут, а не питоне

---

> Неужели, когда мы проходимся по строкам в файле, каждую строку, к
> которой мы применили strip() нужно ссылать на отдельную переменную?

Кто вам такое сказал? При каждом вызове `strip` будет создан и возвращен новый объект и тот, что раньше был у переменной, будет заменен и удален сборщиком мусора

Поэтому нет разницы, кроме одной – в одной переменной будет оригинальная строка, в другой – обработанная `strip`'ом

---

Нет смысла беспокоиться об эффективности кода, пока проблем с производительностью нет

Comment: щас меня как заминусуют :)

Comment: `Нет смысла беспокоиться об эффективности кода, пока проблем с производительностью нет` - оч. спорное утверждение. Мой извращенный ум сразу нарисовал картинку создания софта для аппарата искусственного дыхания... ;-)

Comment: @MaxU Ой я это представляю)

Comment: В CPython массивы и другие объекты обычно удаляются сразу же после удаления соответствующей переменной, не дожидаясь сборщика мусора

Comment: @MaxU делать аппарат искусственного дыхания на питоне — воистину извращение)

Comment: @andreymal, я ж говорю - "извращенный" 8-D. Но суть не в языке программирования, а в подходе...

Comment: @gil9red я прошу прощения, но не могли бы вы подправить ответ: "Не могу не ответить")

Comment: @KitScribe, без проблем )

Comment: @gil9red да я про опечатку говорил... Но ок)